# How would I use Jlayered pane to get the buttons on top of the background instead of under it?

Tags: java, swing, layout, background, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to get the image background set BEHIND the 3 `JButton`s. As of right now it's painting the background then placing the buttons below with no background (stretch window to see). How would I use `JLayeredPane` to get the background image to the back? 
I'm under the impression that `JLayeredPane` would be the easiest way to do this. I could be wrong wrong though.

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Galaga extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener{

    private JButton startButton, highScoreButton, optionsButton;

    public JPanel buttonPanel, optionsPanel, highScorePanel;

    public Galaga() {
        startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
        highScoreButton = new JButton("High Scores");
        optionsButton = new JButton("Options");

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/Spacebackground.png")));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        buttonPanel.add(highScoreButton);
        buttonPanel.add(optionsButton);

        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        highScoreButton.addActionListener(this);
        optionsButton.addActionListener(this);
        addWindowListener(this);

        add(buttonPanel);
    }
```

Comment: You could do this with a JLaywredPane, but you could also do this by setting a Layout anager to the JLabel and adding the buttons to it instead

Answer (score 2):

You curl simply set a layout manager on the label and add the buttons to it instead...

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/Spacebackground.png"));
    label.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label.add(startButton);
    label.add(highScoreButton);
    label.add(optionsButton);

    add(label);
```

Comment: Kinda wanted to keep it as Panels since I already have the options and highscore panels all set up.

Comment: JLabel is a container, just like JPanel. If you really want to, add the JLabel to another JPanel...